# How to use arrays to find average, minimum and maximum with pointers

Tags: arrays, c

The function arrayAvgMinMax should return values for the average, minimum, and maximum via the pointers that are passed in. The average should also be returned using the normal return mechanism. Use no library functions in your code.

ArrayAvgMinMaxMain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double arrayAvgMinMax(double array[], int length, double *avg, double *min, double *max);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int length = 200;
   double avg, min, max;
   double lowRange=0, highRange=1;
   double divisor = (double) RAND_MAX;
   int i;
   
   if(argc > 1)
      length = atoi(argv[1]);
   if(argc > 2) {
      lowRange = atoi(argv[2]);
      highRange = atoi(argv[3]);
   }
    
   //Initialize values to make it clear if they are not changed.
   avg = min = max = 99999.9999;
 
   double *array = calloc(length, sizeof(double)); 
   srand(131313); // Set the starting seed so we always get the same results
   
   for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      array[i] = lowRange + (highRange-lowRange)*rand()/divisor;
   
   double average = arrayAvgMinMax(array, length, &avg, &min, &max);
   
   printf("avg=%f (%f), min=%f, max = %f\n", avg, average, min, max);
   return 0;
}
```

ArrayAvgMinMaxFunction.c edit this function only

only one for loop for efficiency

```
#include <stdio.h>

double arrayAvgMinMax(double array[], int length, double *avg, double *min, double *max) {
    //one for loop
    int i;
    int sum;
    min=max=&array[i];
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(min > array[i]){
            min = &array[i];
        }
        if(max<array[i]) {
            max = &array[i];
        }
        sum = sum + array[i];
        avg = (double)sum/(i+1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

input: 10000000 100 200

output: avg=149.991665 (149.991665), min=100.000010, max = 199.999993

Comment: `i` is uninitialized when the code executes `min=max=&array[i];` — replace `i` with `0` (zero). Don't calculate `avg` on each iteration — do it once after the loop.  `avg` is a pointer; you should be getting a compilation error for `avg = (double)sum/(i+1);` — `*avg` would be correct.  You sum `double` values into an `int`; that's not good.  Both `min` and `max` are pointers too; you should be using `*min` and `*max` in assignments and references (or create local variables for min and max (`double l_min, l_max;`) and then use those until the end, assigning `*min = l_min; *max = l_max;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with the `avg`, `min` and `max` arguments to the `arrayAvgMinMax` function is *emulating pass by reference*. For that to work you have to remember that the pointers are pointing to *variables*, and you need to set the *values* of those variables. Which means you need to *dereference* the pointers to get the variables they're pointing to.

So the assignments

```
min=max=&array[i];
```

makes no sense (even if `i` is initialized). And neither does comparisons like `min > array[i]`, where you compare the *pointer* `min` to the *value* `array[i]`.

You need to do e.g.

```
*min = *max = array[0];
```

And use e.g. `*min > array[i]`.

Comment: I see that makes sense thanks for the advice I will go and fix this